# VS2012 + TFS DefaultTemplate.xaml Template + custom activity

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have written Custom activity with below code.

and when i am trying to drag and drop the custom assembly and build the application. i am getting below errors.

Error   1   The private implementation of activity '1.149: WritingCeMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    342 39  Template
```

Error   2   The private implementation of activity '1.205: WriteBuildMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    429 203 Template
```

Error   3   The private implementation of activity '1.214: WriteBuildMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    429 203 Template
```

Error   4   The private implementation of activity '1.219: WriteMessageTestName' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    382 98  Template
```

Error   5   The private implementation of activity '1.226: WritexUnitStdOutput' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    372 324 Template
```

Error   6   The private implementation of activity '1.236: WriteBuildMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    376 186 Template
```

Error   7   The private implementation of activity '1.298: WriteBuildMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    397 135 Template
```

Error   8   The private implementation of activity '1.325: Run MSBuild for Project' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.Normal".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    287 29  Template
```

Error   9   The private implementation of activity '1.325: Run MSBuild for Project' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    287 29  Template
```

Error   10  The private implementation of activity '1.432: Run MSBuild for Project' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.Normal".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    177 13  Template
```

Error   11  The private implementation of activity '1.432: Run MSBuild for Project' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    177 13  Template
```

Error   12  The private implementation of activity '1.509: WriteBuildWarning' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    152 5   Template
```

Error   13  The private implementation of activity '1.556: WriteBuildWarning' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    114 3   Template
```

Error   14  The private implementation of activity '1.149: WritingChutzpahConsoleMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   15  The private implementation of activity '1.205: WriteBuildMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   16  The private implementation of activity '1.214: WriteBuildMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   17  The private implementation of activity '1.219: WriteMessageTestName' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   18  The private implementation of activity '1.226: WritexUnitStdOutput' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   19  The private implementation of activity '1.236: WriteBuildMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   20  The private implementation of activity '1.298: WriteBuildMessage' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   21  The private implementation of activity '1.325: Run MSBuild for Project' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.Normal".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   22  The private implementation of activity '1.325: Run MSBuild for Project' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\Defaulter   0   0
```

Error   23  The private implementation of activity '1.432: Run MS Build for Project' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.Normal".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\Default Template .xaml  0   0
```

Error   24  The private implementation of activity '1.432: Run MS Build for Project' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   25  The private implementation of activity '1.509: WriteBuildWarning' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Error   26  The private implementation of activity '1.556: WriteBuildWarning' has the following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "False".
Keyword is not valid as an identifier.

```
C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate.xaml    0   0
```

Please help me out for above error. i already spend 2 days on it.

Comment: Which version of TFS are we talking about? If this is TFS 2010, you must use VS2010 to edit the template.

Comment: TFS 2010 but we are using VS 2012 with Team Explore. how can i resolve it.

Comment: You *must* use Visual Studio 2010 + SP1 + The forward compatibiltiy GDR. You cannot change the build definition from VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can only edit the `BuildProcessTemplate` from the version of Visual Studio that matches the TFS version. So even when you do development from Visual Studio 2012, you need to edit the `BuildPorcessTemplate.xaml` from Visual Studio 2010.

Since VS2012 uses the 2012 client object model binaries, it generates xaml that is not compatible with TFS2010. Due to all the binding redirects in the devenv.exe.config it is not possible to force Visual Studio 2012 to load the 2010 binaries.

As such **you must** use VS2010 to edit the 2010 build process templates. You can install VS2010 and VS2012 side by side if needed.

Alterantively, edit the files by hand, they're just XML.

Comment: But i don't have VS 2010 in my machine. is there any other way to do same?

Comment: even you can find my solution on link Skydrive link (https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=41F7B278AA3890D4!112).

Comment: I have tired to build the custom activity solution is VS 2010 but i am getting below errors.

Comment: I have tired to build the custom activity solution is VS 2010 but i am getting below errors.Error 1 Could not resolve attachable member 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities:TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation'. C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate_Custom.xaml 68 4 Template
Error 3 Could not resolve type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(AssemblyReference)' because could not find one or more of its type arguments. C:\ActivityLibrary1\DefaultTemplate_Custom.xaml 94 6 Template